Reading data from BMP
I have a problem with reading pixels from bmp file. I don't know what's causing the problem. It might be something with padding at the end of row or fseek(). I share important parts of program.
bmp.c
struct pixel* read_data(FILE* stream, const struct bmp_header* header){
    if(stream == NULL || header == NULL) return NULL;
    
    fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_SET);

    size_t row_size = (header->width * sizeof(struct pixel)) + strlen(PADDING_CHAR);
    size_t total_size = row_size * header->height;

    struct pixel* data = (struct pixel*)malloc(total_size);
    if(data == NULL){
        printf("cant allocate");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    size_t pixels_read = fread(data, sizeof(struct pixel), 1, stream);
    
    if(pixels_read == 0){
        free(data);
        return NULL;
    }

    return data;
}

bmp.h
#define PADDING_CHAR "\0"

struct pixel {
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t red;
    //uint8_t alpha;
} __attribute__((__packed__));

/**
 * Read the pixels
 *
 * Reads the data (pixels) from stream representing the image. If the stream
 * is not open or header is not provided, returns `NULL`.
 *
 * @param stream opened stream, where the image data are located
 * @param header the BMP header structure
 * @return the pixels of the image or `NULL` if stream or header are broken
 */
struct pixel* read_data(FILE* stream, const struct bmp_header* header);

header if need (basicaly we use 24bit color)
struct bmp_header{
    uint16_t type;              // "BM" (0x42, 0x4D)
    uint32_t size;              // file size
    uint16_t reserved1;         // not used (0)
    uint16_t reserved2;         // not used (0)
    uint32_t offset;            // offset to image data (54B)
    uint32_t dib_size;          // DIB header size (40B)
    uint32_t width;             // width in pixels
    uint32_t height;            // height in pixels
    uint16_t planes;            // 1
    uint16_t bpp;               // bits per pixel (1/4/8/24)
    uint32_t compression;       // compression type (0/1/2) 0
    uint32_t image_size;        // size of picture in bytes, 0
    uint32_t x_ppm;             // X Pixels per meter (0)
    uint32_t y_ppm;             // X Pixels per meter (0)
    uint32_t num_colors;        // number of colors (0)
    uint32_t important_colors;  // important colors (0)
} __attribute__((__packed__));

There are tests
Given the valid BMP stream And the position in file is correct And valid header When the function is called Then data should be read.

1: 
FILE* stream = "Qk1WAAAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAAAgAAAAQAAAABABgAAAAAACAAAAAjLgAAIy4AAAAAAAAAAAAA////AAAAAAD/AAAA/wAAAAD/AAAA/wAAAAAA/wAAAAA="; // base64 encoded stream
struct bmp_header* header = read_bmp_header(stream);
fseek(stream, offset, SEEK_SET);
Assertion 'read_data(stream, header) == "////AAAA/wAAAP8AAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAA"' failed. [got "Qk1WG21VAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"]

2: 
FILE* stream = "Qk1OAAAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAAAgAAAAMAAAABABgAAAAAABgAAAAjLgAAIy4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/wD/AAD/AAAA/wAAAP////8A/wAA"; // base64 encoded stream
struct bmp_header* header = read_bmp_header(stream);
fseek(stream, offset, SEEK_SET);
Assertion 'read_data(stream, header) == "AAAA/wD//wAAAP8A/////wD/"' failed. [got "Qk1OG21VAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"]

So after the "==" is expected result and in the brackets is my the result from my code. The data is transmitted in base64 format for easy reading.

That's because you're seeking to the start of the file after you've read the header and before you've read the pixels. fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_SET);

#define PADDING_CHAR "\0" What is this supposed to do? And why not ""? You use strlen(PADDING_CHAR) for calculating row size but that will not anything. You need to calculating row size by rounding up to multiple of 4 bytes as far as I remember. Need to check that, but your approach doesn't round at all.

return data; You return from that function after reading one pixel. You should clearly read a few more before you return.

For SO to work properly, you are supposed to provide feedback to findings and suggestions in comments.
